# swipeDismissableNavController is returning previous page and even though it is in start menu

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-jetpack

I am new to android programming and my first wearOS app is working quite well but I have issues with the swipeDismissableNavController as it is always moving back to a previous screen rather than close the app once it reached main menu (swipe left to right on wearOS).

Any idea where / which parameter I would need to take a look at?
Would appreciate any guidance into the right direction!

```
SwipeDismissableNavHost(
            navController = swipeDismissableNavController,
            startDestination = Screen.Landing.route,
            modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
        )
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction project.  If you create a mostly empty project with just this, does it also fail?

Comment: Also the kotlinlang slack has a compose-wear channel that can also help https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up